# How to change title through command prompt and keep System information

Tags: c, windows

I am trying to start a process through the command line but when I use the `/k` option to **cmd** I loose all the system information.  How do I keep this information and is there a possible environment variable that I can change to change the title.

```
//first line where I sprintf commands into a buffer
sprintf(commandLine_buf,"%s  /T:F9 /K TITLE=What is your command ",getenv("ComSpec"))
```

@erksun thanks your suggestion worked. I modified it a bit but it worked. This is what it looked like. below

```
sprintf(commandLine_buf, "cmd /c PROMPT Speak to me$G & TITLE What is your command? & \"%s\"",getenv("ComSpec"));
```

My prompt looks like this:

[image]

But I want it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `cmd /K "VER & PROMPT=Speak to me & TITLE=What is your command"`

Comment: If you're running this via `system`, that already uses `cmd /c`, so you can run something like `sprintf(commandLine_buf, "PROMPT Speak to me$G & TITLE What is your command? & \"%s\"",getenv("ComSpec"))`. This changes the shell prompt and console title and then starts a new interactive shell. The first CMD instance that's started by `system` will wait for the child shell to exit.

Comment: Oh crazy you suggested that @ManthanTilva I already tried something close to that but it did not have the same format as I wanted it has a space at the top between What is your command title and Microsoft Windows bla bla bla.  Thanks for the response but not quiet what I want.

Comment: Something got lost in your comment. You should [edit] your question anyway to add useful information, instead of hiding it in comments.

Comment: @erksun sorry but, what do you mean by running this via system

Comment: How are you running this command line in C? `system`, `spawnl`, `CreateProcess`, `ShellExecute`?

Comment: @eryksun CreateProcess but your solution worked after I messed with it a bit. I ended up using the line that I updated in the question above.

Comment: Add an answer. Use the `ComSpec` value instead of "cmd" for the first part. Also, get the environment variable separately, so you can substitute `"cmd.exe"` in case `ComSpec` isn't defined.

Comment: Thanks @eryksun I posted the answer but was not able to get the comspec to work correctly with out a weird output so I just used the CMD.  It is possible that I may not fully understand and I was trying to implement your solution incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

In the final implementation, I got the `ComSpec` values on a different line and ran the `sprintf` function as seen here:

```
char* ComSpecVar;
ComSpecVar = getenv("ComSpec");
sprintf(commandLine_buf, "cmd /c COLOR F9 & PROMPT Speak to me$G & "
    "TITLE What is your command? & \"%s\"", ComSpecVar);
```

The Subsequent prompt looked like this:

[image]

Comment: If `ComSpec` isn't defined, then `ComSpecVar` will be `NULL`, and you should set it to the string literal `"cmd.exe"`. Also, use this value in both places in the command line and quote the whole command line, e.g. `sprintf(commandLine_buf, "\"%s\" /c \"COLOR F9 & PROMPT Speak to me$G & TITLE What is your command? & \"%s\"\"", ComSpecVar, ComSpecVar)`.

Comment: Alright its funny I tried this exact sprintf before but did not do the bit in the first sentence Ill work on this.